# can not access complete webpage using mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I was trying to save the home page of [usautoforce](http://www.usautoforce.com/Pages/home.aspx) using mechanize.@Ertugrul  According to your answer i have the complete page. but when i tried to access the username and password fields, it gave an Error. I have already set all readonly to false. when i opened the web page in editor there were no html referring to the username and password 
Here is my code in mechanize,

```
br = mechanize.Browser()


br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
#br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'), ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests','1'),('Connection','keep-alive')]

br.open("http://www.usautoforce.com/Pages/home.aspx")
br.set_handle_robots(False) 
print br.response
time.sleep(9)

latest_index = 0
html_replaced = ""
html = br.response().read()


for m in re.finditer('(href|src)(=")(/[^"]+")', html):
    html_replaced += html[latest_index:m.start()] + m.groups()[0]+m.groups()[1] + 'http://www.usautoforce.com' + m.groups()[2]
    latest_index = m.end()


f=open("us.html","w")
f.write(html_replaced)
f.close()

print [form for form in br.forms()][0]

br.set_handle_robots(False) 
print br.response
time.sleep(9)
html = br.response().read()

br.select_form(nr=0)
time.sleep(2)

#for control in br.form.controls:
 #   print control
  #  print "type=%s, name=%s value=%s" % (control.type, control.name, br[control.name])

br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
br.form["nexpartuname"] = "abc"

br.form["pwd"] = "xyz"
br.submit()
```

Here is the error:

```
  File "haha.py", line 60, in <module>
    br.form["nexpartuname"] = "clack"
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 2775, in __setitem__
    control = self.find_control(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 3096, in find_control
    return self._find_control(name, type, kind, id, label, predicate, nr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_form.py", line 3180, in _find_control
    raise ControlNotFoundError("no control matching "+description)
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'nexpartuname'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mechanize doesn't execute javascript. The site you're trying to access is also saying 'Please enable scripts...'.

Since there is no way to enable js in mechanize I personally recommend you using phantomjs.

But the real problem here is not javascript, it is urls. Since the urls in that website are relative it doesn't behave as expected when you just download and open the html code.

You have to convert all relative urls to absolute urls. Use this code before writing html to a file. Write the html_replaced str instead of html str to file.

```
latest_index = 0
html_replaced = ""

for m in re.finditer('(href|src)(=")(/[^"]+")', html):
    html_replaced += html[latest_index:m.start()] + m.groups()[0]+m.groups()[1] + 'http://www.usautoforce.com' + m.groups()[2]
    latest_index = m.end()
```

Comment: but when i tried to open it manually  after disabling javascripts in the browser it working fiine.

Comment: @user3809411 You're right. The real problem is relative urls. Please check the updated answer.